# python telegrambot задать вопрос пользователю в цикле

Tags: python, telegram-bot

подскажите,пожалуйста, пытаюсь сделать чтобы телеграм бот в цикле выдавал примеры и проверял их решение.
Но не происходит остановки на ожидание ввода пользователем данных, а код выполняется дальше. Простой пример кода:
Как сделать чтобы бот ожидал ввода данных ( аналог input) и только получив ответ продолжал цикл. Спасибо.

```
def start_primery_maths(message):
    quantity = int(message.text)
    for n in range(quantity):
        a = randint(0, 10)
        b = randint(0, 10)
        answer = a + b
        my_first_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{a} + {b} = ')
        my_first_bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_answer_from_user, answer)



def get_answer_from_user(message, answer):
    if int(answer) == int(message.text):
        my_first_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верно')
    else:
        my_first_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверно!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение, может кому то пригодится. Пример опишу ниже:

```
def start_primery_maths(message):
    a = randint(0, 10)
    b = randint(0, 10)
    answer = a + b
    my_first_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{a} + {b} = ')
    my_first_bot.register_next_step_handler(message,get_answer_from_user, answer)


def get_answer_from_user(message, answer):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        if int(answer) == int(message.text):
            my_first_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верно')
            start_primery_maths(message)
        else:
            my_first_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'не верно!')
            start_primery_maths(message)
    else:
        if message.text.lower() == 'стоп':
            my_first_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Хорошо, хватит пока примеров')
        else:
            my_first_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'я тебя не понимаю....')
            start_primery_maths(message)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]